# Exception while passing the date from java to ireports

Tags: java, datetime, jasper-reports

I have created a report for attendance,where the report runs based on start date and end date.It is working fine in ireports designer.
In ireports i have created a parameters as shown below.

```
$P{StartDate}      -->**parameter class** java.util.date
$P{EndDate}        -->**parameter class** java.util.date
$P{Class_startdate}-->**parameter class** java.lang.string
                   -->**value expression**(($P{StartDate} == null || $P{StartDate}.equals("")) ? "" : "AND cdate.curr_classdate >= TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime()).toString() + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd')") 
$P{Class_enddate}  -->**parameter class** java.lang.string
                   -->**value expression**(($P{EndDate} == null || $P{EndDate}.equals("")) ? "" : "AND cdate.curr_classdate >= TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date($P{EndDate}.getTime()).toString() + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd')")
```

**When the same report runs through java file raising an exception as shown below.**

```
Exceptiionnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : ($P{StartDate} == null || $P{StartDate}.equals("")) ? "" : "AND cdate.curr_classdate >= TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime()).toString() + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd')"file2application/pdf
```

My servlet code,

```
  try {
       System.out.println("Start ....");

          String jrxmlFileName = "D:/ForReports/AttendanceReport.jrxml";
          String jasperFileName = "D:/ForReports/AttendanceReport.jasper";
             JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFileName, jasperFileName);

           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

           String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openbravo";
           String dbUname = "postgres";
           String dbPwd = "password";
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUname, dbPwd);
                      Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          map.put("Course_ID", request.getParameter("param1"));
          map.put("StartDate", request.getParameter("param2"));
          map.put("EndDate", request.getParameter("param3"));
           JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFileName);
          JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conn);
          JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,
              "D:/ForReports/Downloads/" + request.getParameter("param1") + ".pdf");
          System.out.println("Done exporting pdf format to view");
          // JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);

          conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.print("Exceptiion" + e);
        }
```

Please,suggest with your answers how to format the date and pass the date.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: debug in java side and check what value you are setting in map as start and end date?? put the same value manualy in report and check if it is working fine.

Comment: check if you have given same name for date parameters in report as given in key of map. basically I doubt you are getting null value in ireport.

Comment: Yes,The values for parameters which I have given are same.

Comment: Please keep map key and variable name in jasper same. you have given StartDate in jasper and startdate in jasper which isn't correct.

Comment: after changing the parameter name also the same error is showing.

Comment: yes,it as been solved.

Comment: You can answer your own question, Please answer it.